# Bootstrap modal and passing value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

When I click edit, 'id' should pass to own page and modal should pop up. But it doesn't work. Please help me

**PHP and Bootstrap**

```
<tr>        
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>   
    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href='?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Edit</a> </td>          
</tr>
```

**Modal**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
         ------
         -----
         -----
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `href="?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"` variables don't get parsed in single quotes *for one thing*.

Comment: you need javascript to toggle modals. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals - also don't mix PHP and HTML code that way, better create templates and load them via PHP

Comment: Plus, `?id` implies a GET method, so we have no idea how you're fetching that array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass $\_GET variables from a link to a bootstrapmodual?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433765/how-to-pass-get-variables-from-a-link-to-a-bootstrapmodual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class `Edit` in `<a></a>` tag. Use this class to call modal. And, add `data-Id="<?echo $row['id'];?>"`

```
<tr>        
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>   
    <td>
        <a class='Edit' data-toggle="modal" href="#form_modal" data-target="#myModal" data-Id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Edit</a>
    </td>          
</tr>
```

Place this code in **footer**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$('.Edit').click(function(){
    var Id=$(this).attr('data-Id');
    $.ajax({url:"SomePage.php?Id="+Id,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $(".modal-content").html(result);
    }});
});
</script>
```

Create **somepage.php** (If you want to change this page name. Change in `<script></script>` too. Both are related.)

**SomePage.php**

```
<?php
$Id=$_GET['Id'];
?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="fam_id"></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo $Id;?>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

For more info, click [Show data based of selected id on modal popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141862/show-data-based-of-selected-id-on-modal-popup-window-after-click-a-button-php-my/34142325#34142325)

Comment: thank you. but model is pop up window. So, how can i pass the value to existing window? for example, There is a field called "Name", and edit button. If I Press edit button, I need the name as a editable format. So I should pass the id which can take name from database.

Comment: Yess.  `Id` is passed in `<script></script>`. Use that `$Id` to fetch name from DB Table. Put name in editable format. @Nishakar

Comment: And, please let me know what happened there @Nishakar

Comment: Wow its working, thank you so much, really thank you. May i have your fb id plz? And you forgot to put "<?php " in some places :D. And I could not understand , why did you say place that modal format in footer. Without that format also its working. no?

Comment: It's good. That working. But, why i opt this way is when we have 2-3 modal in one project. Then, it will be very handy to use a single modal. Why to create a separate modal for each purpose. Because, i faced some issue 1 year back for having 10-12 modal for each and every purpose. So, i suggest all people to do this way only. *Sorry, I am not in facebook* . **If you think this answer helped you, please tick this as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find it easily.** *Enjoy Coding* @Nishakar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388408/bootstrap-in-data-table-master-doesnt-refresh?noredirect=1#comment56518929_34388408 @nana . do you know how to solve this problem

Comment: Sorry @Nishakar. I don't know the solution of this question.

Comment: Actually i couldn't understand that return part of success
$.ajax({url:"SomePage.php?Id="+Id,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $(".modal-content").html(result);
    }});

Here if this is successful, then something is returned from SomePage.php. What would it return? Normally i do understand that it will return only 'echo' part of php. But in that SomePage.php , there are no php function, only it has got html, but it returns html.. I want to know how this return part works? could you please explain me, or show me a reference book? plz