# How to send vaiable to a Bootstrap modal

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a PHP website and am using Bootstrap for the framework. When I hit a button a modal opens to show some info. I would like to know how to send a variable to this modal from the previous page.

The button is in index.php and the modal code is in modals.php.

This is the modal code:

**index.php**

```
require("modals.php");

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

**modals.php**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm looking for is something like you would do with a url: `<button data-target="myModal&id=1">` and then pick it up with `$varId = $_GET['id']` inside the modal.

Is there a way?

Comment: You have `button` and `modal` in same page? If not on what instance the page opens this `modal`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, Sorry, I forgot to mention that the button is in one file and the modal code is in another file, hence the problem. I updated the OP with this info.

Comment: Like see.. `onclick` of button are you redirecting from `index.php` to `modal.php`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Hi @PoorCadaver: You didn't responded to answer. Whether it works or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index.php** (Give class name `openModal` button, which is used in `<script></script>`. Give `data-id` attribute, pass value to it.)

```
<?php require("modals.php");?>


<button type="button" class="openModal btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-id='1' data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Place this **code** somewhere in same page.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS** (fetch `data-id` from `Open Modal` button. and, pass it to `ajax_modal.php` page)

```
<script>
    $('.openModal').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({url:"ajax_modal.php?id="+id,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".modal-content").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

**ajax_modal.php** (If you are looking to change this page name. Change in `<script></script>` tag too. Both are related.)

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>


<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Your Id : <?echo $id;?></p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

For more info, click here

1. [how-to-pass-current-row-value-in-modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273035/how-to-pass-current-row-value-in-modal/35275254#35275254)
2. [passing-data-via-modal-bootstrap-and-getting-php-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043115/passing-data-via-modal-bootstrap-and-getting-php-variable/33043821#33043821)
3. [bootstrap-modal-and-passing-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360013/bootstrap-modal-and-passing-value/34360394#34360394)
4. [show-data-based-of-selected-id-on-modal-popup-window-after-click-a-button-php-my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141862/show-data-based-of-selected-id-on-modal-popup-window-after-click-a-button-php-my/34142325#34142325)
5. [passing-data-from-page-to-bootstrap-modal-using-sql-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549508/passing-data-from-page-to-bootstrap-modal-using-sql-php/35550456#35550456)

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing something from a previous page set the variable in the query string of the url. You can then get the variable from the url query string using `$_GET`

e.g.

```
<?php $myVar = $_GET["my value"]; ?>
<div class="modal-body">
      <p><?php echo $myVar; ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use pure javascript like so.(No PHP)

**HTML:**

```
<button data-id="myModal1" data-target="#myModal" class="myModalClass">

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some input text where you want to show the passed value.</p>
                <input type="hidden" name="myValue" id="myValue" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and get the value using javascript

```
$(document).on("click", ".myModalClass", function () {
     var myValue = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #myValue").val( myValue ); // myValue has the value 'myModal1'
});
```

Comment: So I send the variable with data-id? Do I have to put my modal html inside of the javascript code (where you have printed alert() )?

Comment: No you can keep the modal where it already is. let me update the answer to clear your doubts.